# How to split the data in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

JS code:

```
$scope.records={"0.19", "C:0.13", "C:0.196|D:0.23"} 
    .filter('filterOutput', function () {
        return function (input) {
            if (input.indexOf(":") != -1) {
                var out = input
                    .split('|')
                    .map(function (v) {
                        var s = v.split(':')
                        return s[0] + ':' + (Number(s[1]) * 100) + "%"
                    })
                    .join()
                return out;
            } else {
                return input * 100 + "%";
            }
        }
    })
```

HTML code:

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records|filterOutput">{{x}}</h1>
```

I want output:

> "19%""C:13%""C:19.6%|D:23%"

But `console.log`:

> TypeError: input.indexOf is not a function

What should I do?
How to split the data in AngularJS?

Comment: I'm wondering how your statement $scope.records={"0.19","C:0.13","C:0.196|D:0.23"} executed ? Moreover indexOf works for array and string. do a console.log below $scope.records={"0.19","C:0.13","C:0.196|D:0.23"} or {{records}} on html to see if it has anything in records

Comment: The problem there is that you have an object and not an array **indexOf** works on arrays and strings.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: $scope.records itself is not a valid json, it cannot be used with ng-repeat. ng-repeat needs an array to repeat not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code to get the desired output.

Html code

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records track by $index">{{x|filterOutput}}</h1>
```

Variable value

```
$scope.records=["0.19","C:0.13","C:0.196|D:0.23"];
```

AngularJS Filter

```
.filter('filterOutput', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (input.indexOf(":") != -1) {
            var out = input
                .split('|')
                .map(function (v) {
                    var s = v.split(':')
                    return s[0] + ':' + (Number(s[1]) * 100) + "%"
                })
                .join('|')
            return out;
        } else {
            return input * 100 + "%";
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you . And I do this in your js ` var _input=input+"" ` .It can also solve mypromble.Can I ask you another question~ I hava one data `C:0.28`then the output is `28.000000000000000004%` I think I didn't deal with some of the details.

Comment: if you want to restrict the decimal points then you can use .toFixed(decimal_point value) to variable which is holding the number value.

You can use below mentioned code in the filter for return


`return s[0] + ':' + (Number(s[1]) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"`

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to get the expected result as mentioned, Please check the code below. 
I've created a fiddle for better understanding [here](http://jsfiddle.net/suzo/fv8kagfu/19/)

**Controller:**

```
.controller('FilterController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.records = ["0.19","C:0.13","C:0.196|D:0.23"];
});
```

**Filter :**

```
.filter('filterOutput', function () {
        return function (inputArray) {
         return inputArray.map(function (input){
                 if (input.indexOf(":") != -1) {
                var out = input
                    .split('|')
                    .map(function (v) {
                        var s = v.split(':')
                        return s[0] + ':' + (Number(s[1]) * 100) + "%"
                    })
                    .join('|')
                return out;
            } else {
                return input * 100 + "%";
            }
         });
        }
    });
```